# How to write sql query for displaying daterange?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to SQL Server 2008. I have a table like shown here:

`student` table :

```
create student
(
     id int, 
     score varchar(10), 
     marks varchar(10),
     date datetime 
)     

id   score marke date ... so on
--------------------------------
1     34    13   3-6-2012
2     50    14   3-7-2012
3     25    9    3-2-2012
1     20    5    2-2-2013
1     10    4    2-7-2013...so on
```

I want to display table like this for particular id only

```
 6-june  2012-2013    34     13
 2-feb   2013-2014    20      5
 7 -july 2014-2013    10      4
```

Note: it starts  from june2012 to july2013.

Note: whenever insert any date to table that should be updated and display in table in ascending order

Note: we need to add any column to that table and we need to add any table.

From that table student from that date column we have been use

Please help me thanks advance. At least write query for daterange

Comment: This looks like an SQL question, not c# or winforms.  Please tag accordingly, or better explain the problem.  Use the formatting tools to better display what you have and what you need.

Comment: editing the question is almost impossible...

Comment: sry for mistake .Actuvally  this  query i am using  in stored crytsal report

Answer (score 0):

You mean like:

```
SELECT date, score, marks WHERE id = 1 ORDER BY DATE
```

Instead of 1 use whatever ID you want...

Comment: thanks for replying me then how display range like 2012-2013. Actuavlly i want to dispaly range hepl me

Comment: SELECT date, score, marks WHERE id = 1 and date between '2011/02/25' and '2011/02/27' ORDER BY DATE